# Get order total without fees and discounts in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I have dynamically added some negative fees to woocommerce cart using

`$woocommerce->cart->add_fee();` function. Now i want to get order total price

from `WC_Order()` class without counting any fee or even discounts and shipping fee.

I tested `WC_Order()::get_total()` but it return zero if i the total price be $10 and i added a negative fee of $15 like this

```
function add_custom_fee() {
     global $woocommerce;
     $woocommerce->cart->add_fee(__('Custom', 'woocommerce'), -15);
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_fee' );
```

I want to get it in a hook after user submit order this is the hook

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete','myfunc');

function myfunc($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $customer = $order->get_customer_id();
    $price = $order->get_total(); // this return zero if i added fee to order
}
```

Comment: Never used WooCommerce and never will be however the documentation tells me there are functions for that in the cart class: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html

Are you talking about the **order** totals or **cart** totals? Confused here ...

Comment: No matter which one i only want total price without added fees as i said but it's better to be order total.

Comment: Give us some more information, do you want to get it before the order is being created or after?

Give us all possible information you can think of and sources you've tried.

Comment: I updated my question thanks for your advise.

Comment: What does: `get_order_item_totals` return?
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#1907-1927

Comment: It returns nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169427/discussion-between-mike-m-and-mahdi-azarm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your code is a little outdated for the cart negative fee part:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_flat_discount', 20, 1 );
function custom_flat_discount( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $cart->add_fee( __("Discount", "woocommerce"), -15 );
}
```

> Now what you have to know is that a **negative fee** always apply taxes.

To get the **order gran total excluding all discounts** you will use the following in your function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'action_payment_complete', 20, 1 );
function action_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
    // get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // Initialising variables
    $subtotal = $subtotal_taxes = 0; 

    // Get order items subtotal and subtotal tax
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        $subtotal += (double) $item->get_subtotal();
        $subtotal_taxes += (double) $item->get_subtotal_tax();
    }
    // Order subtotal without any discounts, shipping…
    $order_subtotal = $subtotal + $subtotal_taxes;

    // Get order shipping totals
    $shipping_total = $order->get_shipping_total();
    $shipping_total_tax = $order->get_shipping_tax();

    // Order subtotal with shipping but without any discounts
    $order_subtotal_with_shipping = round($order_subtotal + $shipping_total + $shipping_total_tax, 2);

    // Your other code goes here
}
```

Alternatively you can use `woocommerce_order_status_{$status_transition[to]}` action hook on "processing" and "completed" **paid** statuses:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'action_order_status_completed', 20, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'action_order_status_completed', 20, 2 );
function action_order_status_completed( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Initialising variables
    $subtotal = $subtotal_taxes = 0; 

    // Get order items subtotal and subtotal tax
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        $subtotal += (double) $item->get_subtotal();
        $subtotal_taxes += (double) $item->get_subtotal_tax();
    }
    // Order subtotal without any discounts, shipping…
    $order_subtotal = $subtotal + $subtotal_taxes;

    // Get order shipping totals
    $shipping_total = $order->get_shipping_total();
    $shipping_total_tax = $order->get_shipping_tax();

    // Order subtotal with shipping but without any discounts
    $order_subtotal_with_shipping = round($order_subtotal + $shipping_total + $shipping_total_tax, 2);

    // Your other code goes here
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.